# Symfony inheritance isn't working EasyAdmin bundle

Tags: inheritance, twig, bundle, symfony, symfony2-easyadmin

I'm using symfony 3 with EasyAdminBundle

I created a new bundle called AdminBundle child of EasyAdminBundle (to override)

```
namespace AdminBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AdminBundle extends Bundle {

    public function getParent(){

        return 'EasyAdminBundle';
    }

}
```

I overrided a method in the controller and it works fine, but when I tried to override a twig template it isn't working...

I created my twig file in `AdminBundle/Resources/views/default/list.html.twig`

The original is in `vendor/javiereguiluz/easyadmin-bundle/Resources/views/default/list.html.twig`

How to fix?
(I cleared the caches many times...)

Comment: Please post your twig code that you say you are trying to override.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the `EasyAdminBundle:default:index.html.twig` is rendered, Symfony actually looks in two different locations for the template:

1. app/Resources/EasyAdminBundle/views/default/index.html.twig
2. src/AdminBundle/Resources/views/default/index.html.twig

Your approach is the second option to do this, **BUT**:

> The overriding of resources only works when you refer to resources with the `@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml` method. If you refer to resources without using the @BundleName shortcut, they can't be overridden in this way. [[See Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/inheritance.html#overriding-resources-templates-routing-etc)]

To override the bundle template, just copy the `index.html.twig` template from the bundle to `app/Resources/EasyAdminBundle/views/default/index.html.twig` (the `app/Resources/EasyAdminBundle` directory won't exist, so you'll need to create it). [[See Doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/overriding.html)]

> If you add a template in a new location, you may need to clear your cache (`php bin/console cache:clear`), even if you are in debug mode.

Comment: Mhm, So EasyAdmin internally don't handle resources with the @FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml methon and use instead the @BundleName method so I can't override from a child bundle but I have to put files in app/Resources, right?

Comment: I'm no sure if EasyAdmin internally don't handle resources with @BundleName, but yes, put files in app/Resources always works.